# Use image ACF with get_previous_post

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image, advanced-custom-fields

In an article I want to have the link of the previous article, including the title of the article and a ACF custom image. 
I now how to make the link of the previous title project :

```
<?php
$prev_post = get_previous_post();
if (!empty( $prev_post )): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $prev_post->guid ?>">
<?php echo $prev_post->post_title ?>            
</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

Here's my ACF code for the current image :

```
<?php 
$image = get_field('image_cover');
if( !empty($image) ): ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

But how to do the same thing (get_previous_link) for my ACF image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$image = get_field('image_cover', $prev_post->ID);
```

This will get the custom field image_cover from the previous post using the ID supplied by the previous post object.